# What does it means figures are in contents?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I am going to submit the paper to a journal. They required that the figures and tables are in contents. That means I will write text and add the figure after text, Is it right?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give a direct quote of what they journal asked for? I am having trouble understanding exactly what is asked in this question. Did they mean the content of the paper, or the table of contents?

Comment: My journal is http://www.journals.elsevier.com/digital-signal-processing/

Comment: @user3051460 can you edit a link to the author instructions and quote exactly what they are saying. I did not see much about where figures go.

Answer (score 1):

I think they want the figures and the body content all to be together, I am assuming that you are seperating them.